# How to add data to related tables in supabase - with nextjs app router?

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-database

I have a feeds table and a relatedMaterials table. My relatedMaterials table has a foreign key to the feeds table. I am trying to figure out how to post relatedMaterials to the supabse db, when the feed form is submitted. This is what I am trying:

```
"use client";
import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import dayjs from "dayjs";
import advancedFormat from "dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat";

dayjs.extend(advancedFormat);

import { addFeed, addRelatedMaterials } from "./newFeedFormSubmit";

export type FeedType = Database["public"]["Tables"]["feeds"]["Row"];

export type RelatedMaterialsType = {
  id?: number;
  feedId?: number;
  title: string;
  url: string | null;
  isReference: boolean;
};

export default function Feed({ feed }: { feed?: FeedType }) {

  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>();

  // const [materials, setMaterials] = useState<RelatedMaterialsType[]>([{ id: 0, title: "", url: "", isReference: false }]);
  const [materials, setMaterials] = useState<RelatedMaterialsType[]>([]);

  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

  const [feeds, setFeeds] = useState<any[]>([]);

  
  const addMaterial = () => {
    setMaterials([...materials, { title: "", url: "", isReference: false }]);
  };

  const removeMaterial = (index: number) => {
    const newMaterials = [...materials];
    newMaterials.splice(index, 1);
    setMaterials(newMaterials);
  };

  

  const updateMaterial = (
    index: number,
    field: keyof RelatedMaterialsType,
    value: any
  ) => {
    const newMaterials = [...materials];
    newMaterials[index][field] = value as never;
    setMaterials(newMaterials);
  };

  const handleReferenceChange = (index: number) => {
    const updatedMaterials = [...materials];
    updatedMaterials[index].isReference = !updatedMaterials[index].isReference;
    setMaterials(updatedMaterials);
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleFormSubmit called");
  
    if (formRef.current) {
      console.log("Inside formRef.current block");
      const formData = new FormData(formRef.current);
  
      console.log("Feed data:");
      const formDataArray = Array.from(formData.entries());
      for (const [key, value] of formDataArray) {
        console.log(key, value);
      }
  
      try {
        const feedId = await addFeed(formData, materials);
        if (materials.length) {
          console.log("Adding related material:", materials);
  
          const materialPromises = materials.map((material) =>
            addRelatedMaterials(feedId, material)
          );
  
          const materialResults = await Promise.all(materialPromises);
  
          console.log("Material results:", materialResults);
        }
        formRef.current.reset(); // Reset the form even if there's an error
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle and log the error
        console.error("Error in handleFormSubmit:", error);
      }
    }
  };
  
  
  

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} ref={formRef}>
          <div className="mb-2 w-full">
            <input name="title" className="bg-lighter border-none  w-full" />
          </div>
            <textarea
              rows={5}
              name="blurb"
              className="bg-lighter border-none  w-full"
            />
          </div>
          
          <div>
            {materials.map((material, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <div className="mb-2">
                  <label>Material Title</label>
                  <input
                    value={material.title}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      updateMaterial(index, "title", e.target.value)
                    }
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-2">
                  <label>Material URL (optional)</label>
                  <input
                    value={material.url || ""}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      updateMaterial(index, "url", e.target.value)
                    }
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-2">
                  <label className="mr-2">Is Reference</label>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={material.isReference}
                    onChange={() => handleReferenceChange(index)}
                    className="cursor-pointer"
                  />
                </div>

                <button type="button" onClick={() => removeMaterial(index)}>
                  Remove Material
                </button>
              </div>
            ))}
            <button type="button" onClick={addMaterial}>
              Add More Materials
            </button>
          </div>

          <button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-linkStyle hover:bg-linkOnHover text-light my-4 py-2 px-4 rounded-none"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

My server action is:

```
["use server";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import type { FeedType } from './FeedForm';
import { RelatedMaterialsType } from './FeedForm';

import { supabase } from './serverHelpers'; 

type SupabaseResponse<T> = {
  data: T[] | null;
  error: any;
};

export const addFeed = async (formData: FormData, materials: RelatedMaterialsType[]) => {
  const title = String(formData.get("title"));
  const blurb = String(formData.get("blurb"));

  const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (!user) throw new Error("No user found");

  console.log("Attempting to add feed", { title, published });

  try {
    const response: SupabaseResponse<FeedType> = await supabase
      .from("feeds")
      .insert({
        title, published, link, publicationDate, publisherId, region, blurb, format, primaryCategory, coverageArea, secondaryCategory, created_by: user.id 
      });
    
    if (!response.data || response.data.length === 0) {
        

        throw new Error("Failed to add feed feed");
      }
      
    console.log("Materials array:", materials);

    // Extract relatedMaterials data from formData
    const feedId = response.data[0].id;
    console.log("Feed ID obtained:", feedId);


    if (materials) {
        for (let material of materials) {
        console.log("Adding related material:", material);
    
        await supabase
            .from("relatedMaterials")
            .insert({
            feedId: feedId,
            title: material.title,
            url: material.url,
            isReference: material.isReference
            });
        }
    }
  

    revalidatePath("/");

    return feedId;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in addFeed:", error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error
  }
};


export const addRelatedMaterials = async (feedId: number, material: RelatedMaterialsType) => {
    const { title, url, isReference } = material;
    console.log("Adding related material:", material);
    try {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.from("relatedMaterials").insert({
            feedId,
            title,
            url,
            isReference
        });

        if (error) {
            console.error("Error adding related material:", error);
            throw error;
        }
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding related material:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
](`url`)
```

I'm using a server helper to define the supabase:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { createServerActionClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";

const cookieStore = cookies();
const supabase = createServerActionClient<Database>({ cookies: () => cookieStore });

export { supabase };
```

When I load this form and complete it, the feeds table populates. the relatedMaterials table does not. Both tables have RLS policies that allow anyone to do everything.

The network tab shows a 500 error, but the payload correctly identifies the form elements (wrapped in an array - that i cant tell if its syntax from the network tab or coming from something ive done).

> ["$K1",[{"title":"qw","url":"qw","isReference":true}]]

the console logs inside the try block of the handleFormSubmit do not render (even the one that says feed added successfully).

The code breaks at this error log:

```
43 | throw new Error("Failed to add feed feed");
| ^
44 | }
```

Can anyone show me how I can make a related table submission in this context?